# How could I store 3D arrays (extracting netcdf variables) which I want to concatenate from a for loop?

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop, netcdf

I'm extracting the variable `A` with `A.size` `[1,71,57]` from each of the `333` NetCDF files with a `for` loop through the path where I have the files.
I would need to concatenate the variables in an array `Mat_A` with the size `[333,71,57]`.
How could I store `A` arrays when I extract them?

Thank you.

Comment: `np.save(file, A)`?

Comment: `np.concatenate` (and family) works best when given a list of arrays.  So a list of the `A` arrays is the best starting point.

Comment: In case the dimensions of A are correctly defined and the pieces you read are aligned, you may try `xarray`, which can just concatenate them automatically. No need for a `for loop`.

Comment: @hpaulj thank you. I solved with np.concatenate!!